# Integrate by reducing to standard form $\int \frac{e^{-\tan z}}{\cot^2 z} dz $

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Integrate by reducing to standard form $\int  \frac{e^{-\tan z}}{\cot^2 z} dz $

My steps:

Let $\tan z=u$, then $\frac{1}{\cot^2 z}dz=\tan^2zdz=(\sec^2z-1)dz$, so that $\sec^2zdz=du$.

So one part is $\int e^{-u}du$, but what about the other part? $\int e^{-\tan z}dz$?

Comment: $
\begin{aligned}
u & =\tan z \\
\Rightarrow d u & =\sec ^2 z d z  =\left(1+u^2\right) d z \\
\Rightarrow d z & =\frac{d u}{1+u^2} \\
\Rightarrow I & =\int \frac{e^{-u} d u}{1+u^2}
\end{aligned}
$

Comment: But how do I integrate this? By parts?

Comment: It is not elementary and can’t be evaluated  using integration by parts.

Comment: So this does not have any solution as such?

Answer (score 1):

There is a non elementary solution for $$I=\int \frac{e^{-\tan( z)}}{\cot^2 (z)} dz$$

$$\tan(z)=x \quad \implies\quad z=\tan^{-1}(x)\quad \implies\quad dz=\frac{dx}{x^2+1}$$
$$I=\int\frac{ x^2}{x^2+1}e^{-x}\,dx$$ Write
$$\frac{ x^2}{x^2+1}=\frac{ x^2}{(x+i)(x-i)}=1-\frac{i}{2 (x+i)}+\frac{i}{2 (x-i)}$$ So, you face integrals of the type
$$J(a)=\int \frac {e^{-x}}{x+a} \,dx$$
Let $x+a=t$
$$J(a)=e^a \int \frac {e^{-t}}{t} \,dt=\text{Ei}(-t)$$ where appears the exponential integral function.